# Organic Groups Registration Codes / Keys

Tags: users, 6

I am trying to set up a registration code/key for my site. I know these modules (listed below) assign a code or i can assign a key to each organic group.

The issue i am having that if i select Group A but provide code for Group B it puts the registered user in both groups A & B.

I would like it to work as follows: I provide Group A code, I select Group A from dropdown and then i will be put in that group. If i provide Group A code, but select Group B it should prompt an error or vice versa.

Any suggestions would help!

Module Links:

- [Organic Groups Registration Codes](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_reg_codes)
- [Organic Groups Registration Keys](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_reg_keys)

Comment: I should also mention that i am on Drupal 6.